# How to tweak gatsby routing

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I have a simple gatsby site where I wish to share a route between the site root and a separate page component.

So I want:

```
1.     / => to go to the component in pages/myComponent
2.     /myComponent/ => to go to the component in pages/myComponent
```

Situation 2 is catered for out of the box, but I'm not sure how I can get the root so go to anything other than `pages/index.js`

I have tried to nest `myComponent` inside `index.js` like this, but I can't get the right setup for pages queries, so I presume routing is the way to go?

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import myComponent from './myComponent'

export default function IndexPage ({ data }) {
  return (<myComponent data={data}/>)
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`...some query`;
```

Comment: hi! did you come up with a solution yet? I'm in the same situation right now. I just want /me to be my index page because it seems that the activeLink option doesn't really work if you are linking to "/" (stays active all the time because the url doesn't change "enough" i guess).